# Primeng: multiselect not filled

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm running against filling options on `p-multiSelect`.

HTML code is:

```
<p-multiSelect
  name="ambits"
  [options]="scopes$ | async">
</p-multiSelect>
```

where `scopes$` is:

```
public scopes$: Observable<Array<ApplicationScope>>;
constructor(
    private service: AplicacionsSubcomponentService
) {
    this.scopes$ = service.getScopes()
        .pipe((take(1)));
}
```

Nevertheless, my multiselect options are empty, it's not filled by `Observable<Array<ApplicationScope>>` `async` subscription.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue is the way you call services. `AplicacionsSubcomponentService` (this probably has typos and must be `ApplicationsSubcomponentService`) is actually part of your component and should be referenced using `this`. Try it that way:

```js
public scopes$: Observable<Array<ApplicationScope>>;

constructor(private readonly service: AplicacionsSubcomponentService) {
    this.scopes$ = this.service.getScopes().pipe(take(1));
}
```

Also if you want to use custom labels (PrimeNG by default looks for property called `label`) you need to supply it's name in template:

```html
<p-multiSelect name="ambits" [options]="scopes$ | async" optionLabel="name">
</p-multiSelect>
```

Here is a working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z2lpf1) example. Keep in mind that I've used a fake service.